Monaco Editor Error executing Lua script: [string "chunk"]:1: unexpected symbol near '\'
Im trying to use monaco editor instead my textbox in WPF,everything fine one day i add something which doesn't impact my Monaco when i execute (i use Lua script test)
if you need any information let me know!
I want my Monaco Editor execute script but it wont T_T
